# computes the length of list which contains list (SML)

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

SML length function:

```
fun length(L) =
    if (L=nil) then 0
    else 1+length(tl(L));
```

For example:

```
length [1,2,3] = 3;
length [ [5], [4], [3], [2,1] ] = 4;
```

Based on the code, how do I change it if I also want to count the elements in the list of the list?

For example:

```
length [ [5], [4], [3], [2,1] ] = 5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create another function that will use your function as follows:

```
fun d_length ( [] ) = 0
| d_length ( l :: l' ) = length(l) + d_length(l');

d_length[ [5], [4], [3], [2,1] ];
```

Or alternatively, use the build in reducer:

```
List.foldl (fn(e,a) => length(e) + a) 0 [ [5], [4], [3], [2,1] ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to make the comparison `L=nil` as this only works for lists of types that are comparable (e.g. not lists of functions). Rather, you want the pattern matching that Kevin Johnson suggests;

```
fun length [] = 0
  | length (x::xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Or using tail-recursion:

```
fun length xs =
    let fun len [] n = n
          | len (x::xs) n = len xs (1+n)
    in len xs 0 end
```

Unlike `length : 'a list -> int`, this function has type `'a list list -> int`.

The combined length of all sublists can be achieved in a number of ways. E.g.

```
fun length2 xss = List.foldl op+ 0 (List.concat xss)
```

But as Kevin's answer also takes advantage of, there really isn't any point in building a new list with `List.concat xss` when all we do is destroy it again moments later. So to shamelessly rip his solution:

```
fun length2 xss = List.foldl (fn (xs, sum) => length xs + sum) 0 xss
```

which is probably the most readable way to express that function, too, but if you were to try to [*code golf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) that function really short, you could also rewrite the inner closure using higher-order functions:

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y)
fun uncurry f (x, y) = f x y
fun length2 xss = List.foldl (uncurry (curry op+ o length)) 0 xss
```

Comment: It took me a few minutes to understand what you were doing with that curry/uncurry. It's very clever.

Comment: It'd be more clever if `foldl` and `op+` were curried by default and there were no [Value Restriction](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/valrestr.html). Then it'd be `val length2 = foldl (op+ o length) 0`!

Comment: I definitely ran into that value restriction a couple of times when playing around with this. In Haskell you can (I think) do this entire thing in a point-free style, but SML makes it difficult to build up much using `o`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pattern-matching straight recursion version which doesn't use the built-in `length` function but instead computes the total length ("tol") directly:

```
fun tol [] = 0
|   tol ([]::xss) = tol xss
|   tol ((x::xs)::xss) = 1 + tol (xs::xss);
```

The order of parenthesis in the final clause is important. It overrides the right-associativity of `::` so that the `x` in `(x::xs)::xss` is interpreted as the head of the first list in `xss` rather than head of `xss` itself.

The pattern of these answers seems to be to close with a fold, and I don't want to break pattern. Here is a fold which folds into a sum a list obtained by mapping length over a list of lists:

```
fun tol xss = foldl op+ 0 (map length xss);
```